# Interference/White noise through headphones on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VW running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, sound, asus, headphones, audio-jack

I have an Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VW running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dual boot. Whenever I have headphones plugged in, there is a high pitch white noise that comes through. This noise is not there for Windows 10. I've tried disabling Intel power save and muting the mic input through system settings and alsamixer. Even if I disable all system sound the noise is still there.

```
System info: 4.6.0-040600-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
        HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
        HDA Intel PCH at 0xdd428000 irq 137
```

Comment: What happens if you rmmod the Intel audio modules and alsa module? I wonder if its a hardware issue under linux.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with a Win 10 dualboot with Ubuntu 18.04. I have this setup on an Asus G501VW.

According to this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2312163) it was a problem of using the wrong driver under Ubuntu.

I needed to change which driver was used like:

1. Open a terminal
2. Edit the file under `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. To do this, open your favorite program. I typed the following in the terminal to open the nano editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```
3. Within the file, go to the last line and add the line

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: This fixed a high pitch hissing issue with my Asus G501VW running Ubuntu 19.10